# XNA, Do-While basic trouble

Tags: c#, xna, artificial-intelligence, game-physics

I am creating a simple AI for my XNA project.

My Enemy should move from the right to the left after a short periode.

Unfortunately my code skips my first and second Do-While, so my enemy doesn't move :< 5 seconds long. So he just jumps from +-1.X Position

```
while (i <= 1)
    {
        EnemyVelocity.X += 1f;
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        usedTimeRight = timer;
        i++;
    } 

    if (usedTimeRight != 0) 
    {
        do
        { EnemyVelocity.X -= 1f;
          timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        } while ((timer - usedTimeRight) >= 5);
        usedTimeLeft = timer;
        usedTimeRight = 0;
    }
    if (usedTimeLeft != 0)
    {
        do
        { EnemyVelocity.X += 1f;
          timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        while (timer - usedTimeLeft >= 5);
        usedTimeRight = timer;
        usedTimeLeft= 0;
    }
```

Updated...~~~~~~~~~~~

So, now another problem - my enemy is moving left all the time

```
timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

while (i <= 1)
    {
        EnemyVelocity.X -= 1f;
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        usedTimeRight = timer;
        i++;
    }

    if (usedTimeRight != 0 && (timer - usedTimeRight <= 2))
    { 
        int x;

        for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
        {
            EnemyVelocity.X = 1;

        }
        usedTimeLeft = timer;
        usedTimeRight = 0;
    }
  if (usedTimeLeft != 0 && (timer - usedTimeLeft <= 2))
    {
        int x;

        for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
        {
            EnemyVelocity.X = - 1;

        }
        usedTimeRight = timer;
        usedTimeLeft = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the fact that the initial while loop iterates faster so fast that the while loop is exited before `usedTimeRight = timer` > 0. This  means that your fist and second if statments will be false because `useTimeLeft` and `useTimeRight` will always be 0. Try changing this so that the `Timer` variable is equal to 1 upon declaration.

for example:

```
  float timer = 1f;

  while (i <= 1 ) 
            {
                EnemyVelocity.X += 1f;
                timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                usedTimeRight = timer;
                i++;
            } 


            if (usedTimeRight != 0) 
            {
                do
                { EnemyVelocity.X -= 1f;
                  timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                } while ((timer - usedTimeRight) >= 5);
                usedTimeLeft = timer;
                usedTimeRight = 0;
            }
            if (usedTimeLeft != 0)
            {
                do
                { EnemyVelocity.X += 1f;
                  timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                }
                while (timer - usedTimeLeft >= 5);
                usedTimeRight = timer;
                usedTimeLeft= 0;
            }
```

Comment: I've changed my code a bit ( tried to avoid to put timer at the while )   But my character is just moving left now.. ( How to add a new code? ^^) ''

Comment: I think you need to think the code through look at all values at each point

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommand to beginners to use while loops in video games Update loops only when you really need it, as it can stop your game or give you unexpected result (typically things teleporting like in this question) because of difficulties at first to understand how the game inner logic works.

If you need your enemy to do something for five seconds, just save in a variable the gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.totalMilliseconds when it start the action you want and just check in a if if  your savedGameTime is smaller than the total gametime - minus the time you want .

If got it right you want your enemy to move left for five seconds then right for five seconds ? To achieve this you must do something like this
:

```
        float delayBetweenMoves = 5f;
        float lastMoveTime = 0f;
        bool isMovingLeft;
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            Move(gameTime);
            enemy.Position += (enemy.VelocityX * enemy.Speed);
        }
        private void Move(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if(lastMoveTime < gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMiliseconds - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delayBetweenMoves))
            {
                lastMoveTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMiliseconds;
                if (isMovingLeft)
                {
                    enemy.VelocityX = -1;
                    isMovingLeft = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    enemy.VelocityX = +1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've solved my problem on the almost the same way as you suggested =). Thank you.  Btw, I've noticed, that it's really "hard" to exit the while-loop -> so my programm just freezes :<

Comment: A blanket, absolute ban on `while` loops inside `Update` is not good advice.  There is no inherent reason to avoid using `while` there. It is true that you shouldn't use `while` in the way he was originally using it, outright banning it entirely just teaches Voodoo Programming.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I'm quite surprised you think it's a terrible recommandation to say a beginner to never use a potentially infinite loop in a video game. In video games you mostly need to do things over time, and as fast as possible, i barely see any situation where a while loop would be best suited in an update. But i totally admit I can be wrong so i would be glad if could enlight me on this ^^

Comment: One example that immediately comes to mind is walking a tree structure.  Game Entities are often placed in a tree structure, and sometimes it is required to walk parent nodes looking for a particular property.  My main problem with your answer is your use of absolutes, like "Never".  If you could rephrase some of that, I would remove my objection.

Comment: Done. I see what you mean, and i forgot that this site helps people over time, so yes my answer was dedicated to the specific person who asked it at this specifc time, so i assumed he wasn't going to implement this kind of logic before at least months, sorry